# SendFailedException is not doing its work

Tags: java, email, exception, smtp, jakarta-mail

In catch block of sending mail with `Javamail API` I'm using `instanceof` to categorize exceptions `AuthenticationFailedException` is doing its job But `SendFailedException` is not. I'm testing my application with some mail addresses that include some valid and some invalid addresses **But** `SendFailedException` do not trigger on invalid addresses.
Here is how I'm using catch block

```
catch (MessagingException ex) {
            if (ex instanceof AuthenticationFailedException) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception: \n" + "Athentication failed due to invalid sender mail or password\n");
            } else if (ex instanceof SendFailedException) {

                SendFailedException e = (SendFailedException) ex;
                final Address[] invalidAddresses = e.getInvalidAddresses();

                setFailedAddresses(invalidAddresses);
                final Address[] validSentAddresses = e.getValidSentAddresses();
                setConfirmedAddresses(validSentAddresses);
                final Address[] validUnsentAddresses = e.getValidUnsentAddresses();
                resend(validUnsentAddresses);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception: \n: " + "invalid mail address = "+invalidAddresses.length+"\nvalid addrs = "+validSentAddresses.length+"\nvalid not treated = "+validUnsentAddresses.length);
            } else if (ex instanceof NoSuchProviderException) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception: \n " + "No provider found with the name you specified");
```

Can you point out what where I'm wrong?

My application runs fine and send mails to valid addresses But exception not arise on invalid addresses.
Actually program do not enter into this exception.

Here is how I add Recipients

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(addrsString));
```

Where: `addrsString` is a string containing comma separated mail.
What I want is it should add invalid addresses to an array an shown in `exception` code that it is not doing right now.

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ explains why [you might not get a SendFailedException for invalid addresses](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr).

Comment: Thanks @BillShannon so how can we deal with invalid addresses if these are not validated with primary server (means server through which we are sending)

Comment: See the following item in the JavaMail FAQ.